# Максимум среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы

Tags: c++, циклы, матрицы

Есть ли какой-то простой алгоритм нахождения: Максимума среди сумм элементов диагоналей, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы?
На форуме смотрел темы, программы какие-то слишком сложные 
По условию: матрица целочисленная, n * n, у меня задан размер 4 * 4
Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду благодарен

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: Алгоритм простой и фактически буквально  описан в самом задании: 1. Найти суммы, 2. Выбрать максимум. Ничего другого тут быть не может.

Comment: @AnT ну я не знаю как пройтись по параллельным диагоналями, поэтому и спросил

Comment: Диагонали - это у которых и строка и столбец при переходе к следующей клетке увеличиваются на 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Да при таком размере матрицы просто считайте все диагонали и не заморачивайтесь.

Все равно вам придется суммировать все элементы матрицы (не в одну сумму, понятно), так что меньше, чем O(N^2) вы все равно не получите. Больше тоже :)

Код примерно такой (`v` - матрица):

```
int max = v[0][N-1];
for(int k = -N+1; k < N; ++k)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = std::max(0,k), j = std::max(-k,0); j < std::min(N,N-k); i++, j++)
            sum += v[i][j];
    if (max < sum) max = sum;
}
cout << max << endl;
```

Comment: а можешь как-то упростить код, как-нибудь без длинного for? И можешь пояснить вкратце? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Это и так предельно упрощенный код. Разделите его на два цикла - для отрицательных `k` и для положительных - и посмотрите, как он работает (например, вместо `sum += v[i][j];` выводите пары `cout << " ("<<i<<","<<j<<")";`) - и все станет понятно.

Comment: а не подскажешь как решить проблема max и min не являются членов namespace std?

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` или написать свои :)

Comment: Да, спасибо) А зачем в программе находить мин и макс?

Comment: А чтоб одним циклом обойтись :)